# Jenkins - Download archived artifacts from command line without authentication

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We have set up ldaps authentication for our jenkins server. Our build artifacts are archived and we can download the build artifact using curl -k -u username:password -o artifact-name file-url (we use the switch -k since we have apache set up for redirections). However, we want to set this download artifact automatically on our dev servers and would like to perform this download without the need for authentication. Is there a way to set up this?

Answer (score 2):

The issue https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-1871 explains how this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Have your tried giving group `everyone` permissions to Workspace, and maybe overall Read?